# What is the maximum number of conditions in Azure WAF custom rule?

Tags: azure, azure-waf

I need to block many IPs in WAF custom rule, what is the maximum number of conditions (each condition matches a single IP address) in Azure WAF?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-front-door-service-limits?

Comment: Yes, I still don't see it there... Is it "Nested Conditionals"? I have no idea....